# CFRelease(addressBook) crashes my iOS app

Tags: ios, memory-management, addressbook

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (row == NSNotFound)
        return;

    if (call.uid != kABRecordInvalidID)
    {
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

        ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,
                                                                call.uid);


       // CFRelease(addressBook);// commenting out this makes the program not crash

}
}
```

Here is the issue, static code analysis tells me I have a memory leak because I'm not releasing the address book. I try to release it but if I return to the screen where it was released and call this function again, the app crashes.

So imagine I click on the accessory button on for a `uitableview`. I do what I have to do and return to the original window, I then click on the accessory button of the `uitableview` again and the program crashes with this error:

> -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x618d810

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The address book isn't the thing that's causing the crash (directly).

You aren't retaining your person, you're just getting a reference to him/her. Try using  `CFRetain` on your person.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,
                                                        call.uid);
CFRetain(person);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Comment: Hi Dean, you have solved the issue and my praise.  I'll accept in a sec, but can you help me further to understand why i have to retain the person.  After i return back to the method why is ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,
                call.uid); not storing a person ?  why should i retain it when the delegate method gets called whenever the user presses the accessory button so it should just grab the person again and continue like the first time, i have no clue why i have to retain the person..can you help

Comment: It makes no sense because i've got an addressbook i created, i use that address book to get the person record i want and store it in person variable.  if i release the address book why is the person variable causing the crash???

Comment: You need to better understand Core Foundation. When you receive something with a "Get" in the name, it means you have a temporary pointer to the object. Anything returned by Get is temporary. Create on the otherhand means you own this new object.

Comment: @DavidH is absolutely right but I don't think he went far enough - you need to get a better understanding of memory management and reference counting - just because you know where something is now doesn't mean that it will be there forever, it might go away. You tell iOS not to let it go away by calling `retain` (or `CFRetain` in this case). Take a read through of this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH (and the rect of the memory management docs on there)